# How to do this with 1 query?

Tags: php

```
delete from table1 where user_id = ...
delete from table2 where user_id = ...
delete from table3 where user_id = ...
delete from table4 where user_id = ...
```

I try to make from this 1 query, but not result.

Comment: What library are you using for accessing MySQL? And what have you tried?

Comment: whay do you want to do this? TRUNCATE Table instead, if you want to delete data from table..

Comment: Guys ... he is dealing with multiple tables! :)

Comment: @Jan Hančič I tried this one:
DELETE FROM table1, table2, table3, table4
WHERE table1.user_id=... AND table2.user_id=... AND table3.user_id=... AND table4.user_id=...

This is sql query on php page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that will work

```
DELETE table1.*, table2.*,table3.* FROM table1, table2, table3 
WHERE table1.user_id=? and table2.user_id=? and table3.user_id=?;
```

There's another solution that might work:

```
DELETE FROM table1, table2, table3 
USING table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 USING(user_id) 
    INNER JOIN table3 USING(user_id) 
WHERE table1.user_id= ?
```

Anyway, you can define [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) on the tables with `ON DELETE CASCADE` option, then deleting a record from parent table removes all records from child tables.

Comment: I've checked it locally, both work fine to me. What SQL DB are you using and what version? I thought you were using MySQL >= 4.1

Comment: I hope you understand you need to replace "?" with the user_id value :)